Customising input fields of Joomla login page with template override
I am trying to customise the display of the login page (not the login module) for Joomla 5.
I am working with the file /html/com_users/login/defalt_login.php, which does indeed control the display of the login page.
However, the actual input fields seem to be rendered by the line
<?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('credentials', ['class' => 'com-users-login__input']); ?>
with the result that the actual coding of the fields is found in another place.
Would there by any problem with bypassing this function by hardcoding the field display? Or can I create an override for the form->renderFieldset function?
I thought it would be a fairly straightforward matter to customise this form using an override, but it seems like it's not quite as straightforward as one might have expected!

The field set you are working with, called 'credentials', exists in ../components/com_users/forms/login.xmland in there you can see the two fields, username and password. The renderFieldset() function can be found in ../libraries/src/Form/Form.php along with other functions to manipulate the fields that you may or not find useful to your requirements.
Earlier in the process there will be a loadForm() statement that retrieves login.xml and converts it into an object that can be manipulated. This is where the real power comes from giving you the chance to makes changes to the field(s) before you then render the field or field set.
Depending on the required customisation that you want to perform you can do it several ways.

As you suggest, remove the renderFieldset statement and code your own requirements for displaying each field.

If you need to alter only one of the two fields you can create your own rendering for the field you want to change and use the renderField() function to display the unchanged field defined in the login.xml.


For example
//custom rendering of username field goes here followed by
$this->form->renderField('password')


If your customisation only requires slight changes or additions to the existing fields defined in login.xml then you can use a suitable combination of the setField(), setFieldAttribute(), setValue() and perhaps addNode() before you issue the renderFieldset() statement.

For example
$this->form->setFieldAttribute('username', 'readonly', 'true');
$this->form->renderFieldset('credentials', ['class' => 'com-users-login__input']);


Wow! Thank you, @Irata, for your very detailed and helpful instructions. I really appreciate you taking time to explain all that.
